# How to assert json content in MockRestServiceServer?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-test

How can I tell `MockRestServiceServer` to expect a specific `json` content during a junit `@Test`?

I thought I could expect just a json string as follows:
`.andExpect(content().json(...))`, but that method does not exist. So how could I rewrite the following?

```
private MockRestServiceServer mockServer;
private ObjectMapper objectMapper; //jackson

Person p = new Person();
p.setFirstname("first");
p.setLastname("last");

//mocking a RestTemplate webservice response
mockServer.expect(once(), requestTo("/servlet"))
        .andExpect(content().json(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(p))) //.json() does not exist! why?
        .andRespond(withSuccess(...));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *spring-test* version 5.0.5 the requested `json` method was added.
Now, I am able to write

```
.andExpect(content().json(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(someDTO)))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use for example:

```
 mockServer.expect(ExpectedCount.once(), requestTo(path))
                .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].someField").value("some value"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems your spring-test version is lower than 4.2

Have a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/ContentResultMatchers.html#json-java.lang.String-boolean-

You can update your spring test dependency to be able to use the code that you have provided.

Comment: Using `spring-test-4.3.14.RELEASE`. But what I noticed: the path of `content()` is `org.springframework.test.web.client.match`, not `*.servlet...`. That's because `MockRestServiceServer` is for mocking webservice responses through `RestTemplate`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the ContentRequestMatcher object supports JSON strings starting with [spring-test version 5.0.5.RELEASE](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/match/ContentRequestMatchers.html#json-java.lang.String-).

Answer (score 0):

How about using jsonPath?
andExpect(jsonPath("$.firstname", is("first")))

Comment: I want to create the json from a bean.